# JQuery delegate in Internet Explorer 8 not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, delegates

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>TITLE</title>

 <link type="text/css" href="jsutil/menubar/menu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link type="text/css" media="screen" href="jsutil/tablesorter/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jsutil/menubar/menu.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jsutil/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jsutil/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#tabe").tablesorter();
        $("#tabe").width(600);

        $("#tabe").delegate("td", "click", function() 
        {
         var idCampanha = $(this).parent().find("td:first").html();
         //Seleciona campanha
         alert("clicked in: "+idCampanha);
         event.preventDefault();
        });


        $("#buscacamp").delegate("#bbcamp", "click", function()
        {
            alert("doing post");
            var jqxhr = $.post("php/slistar_campanhas.php", 
            {nome : $("#bcamp").val() },
            function(data)
            {
                $("#tabe > tbody").empty();
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                {
                    var obj = data[i];
                    $("#tabe > tbody:last").append('<tr><td>'+obj.idcampanha+'</td><td>'+obj.nome+'</td></tr>');
                }
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            "json"
             );
             alert("post done");
            jqxhr.error(function(){ alert("Erro") });
            event.preventDefault();
        });


});
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#3B3131">

    <div id="menu">
          ...JUST A WORKING MENU HERE
    </div>




    <div id="corpo" align="center">
        <h1 align="center" style="color:#F8F8F8">Selecionar Campanha</h1>
        <form id="buscacamp">
            <label style="color:#F8F8F8" for="bcamp">Nome da campanha</label>
            <input align="middle" size="35" type="text" name="bcamp" id="bcamp"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="bbcamp" value="OK"/>
        </form>
        <table id="tabe" class="tablesorter" cellspacing="1">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th>Código da Campanha</th>
                                <th>Nome da Campanha</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                                <th>Código da Campanha</th>
                                <th>Nome da Campanha</th>
                        </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
        </table>
        <h1 id="titulo" class="cor" style="color:#F8F8F8">Nova Solicitação</h1>
        <form id="novasol">
            <label for="campanha" style="color:#F8F8F8">Campanha</label>
            <input size="20" type="text" name="campanha" id="campanha" readonly/>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="titulo" style="color:#F8F8F8">Título</label>
            <input size="35" type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="descricao" style="color:#F8F8F8">Descrição</label>
            <textarea  rows="17" cols="55" id="descricao"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <label for="naudios" style="color:#F8F8F8">Número de áudios</label>
            <input size="10" type="text" name="naudios" id="naudios"/>
            <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Chrome Output when #bbcamp is clicked:**
1- alert doing post

2- alert post done

3- add rows to the table and when I click them it shows another alert

**IE 8 output when #bbcamp is clicked:**
1- alert doing post

2- add rows to the table

3- alert post done

4- erases rows and leave me with an empty table

I tryed to use click events and it didnt work either...
I am using jquery 1.7 min

any ideas ??

Comment: You might wanna consider removing the alerts as they stop the execution thread and it could have side effects. Use `console.log` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE is JScript not JavaScript.

```
if(event.preventDefault){
    event.preventDefault();
}
else{
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: jQuery already does this for you.. you know so you don't have to think about this stuff :) Though in the OP he isn't passing the jQuery event to the handlers, so this might actually work.

Comment: Yeah i'll give this +1 even if it's not the right way to do it. You could just add the event parameter to the handlers and it would work without having to do the if check.

Comment: ok, i will do that, but I never heard of suck thing as JScript

Comment: @fredcrs, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript. But if you are using jQuery properly, you usually don't have to worry about it.